# Specifically in terms of nepomorpha, nepidae and further taxonomic classifications

Tags: morphology, etymology, affixes

I believe that the meaning of **morpha** is "form, like, kind". But where does the **nepo** prefix originate from? I seem to get a lot of terms like 'nepotism' in my searches, but I wonder how purely aquatic hemipterans ('sucking' aquatic 'bugs') derive their name from such a prefix.

I felt it must have something more to do with aquatic/water born habitats than a simply relational 'nepotism' like device. Yet I cannot seem to find a Latin or Greek/other classical term that is similar apart from that in nepotism. And if it does simply define itself as some kind of 'relational' form, then why is it juxtaposed so clearly against gerromorpha?

In other words, the surface dwelling bugs-which appears to connote a geo — or at least semi-earth type sense — this leads me to believe I am searching for a water related latin/greek term — or other origin for this nepo-morpha prefix — can you help? Is there some kind of aquatic classical reference within 'nepo'?

Comment: Hello Annette and welcome to Linguistics SE. If you want to add tags, or you think they should be added, you can (and should) post a comment below your question.

Comment: By the way, make sure to explore [Meta] in case you have questions about the site itself.

Comment: The only Greek word in the Middle Liddell that it could come from is _νέποδες (nepodes)_ 'young ones, children'. This is cognate with English _nephew_, and comes from the PIE root _*nepōt_ 'grandson, nephew' (Pok. 764).

Comment: @jlawler: In which of these words do you think a Greek root was used? I can only find Latin *nepa* for *nepidae*.

Comment: _Morph_ is Greek.

Comment: @jlawler: Yes, but *nepa* appears to be Latin-African.

Comment: By the way, there are established protocols for selecting the affixes to be used in biological taxonomy, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank#Terminations_of_names, and -morpha is commonly used for order-level rankings as well.

Comment: I would have liked not to have to google to discover what a nepomorpha was (an insect), otherwise a fine question.

Comment: @kaleissin: (Nepomorpha is plural btw.)

Answer (score 5):

*Nepida* "water-scorpion-like" ([apparently coined by Leach in 1818](http://archive.org/stream/centurydictipt1400whituoft#page/3968/mode/2up)) comes from classical Latin *nepa(s)*, meaning "scorpion" or "crab". The water scorpion or *nepa* is currently a genus under the family of *nepidae*, which in turn fall under the infraorder of *nepomorpha*; according to Wikipedia, it was so named or classified by Linnaeus himself in [1758](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepa_%28genus%29).

Latin *nepa* was borrowed from an African language (according to [Festus, p. 163](http://books.google.nl/books?id=_Ugb6woUJLoC&q=nepa#v=snippet&q=nepa&f=false)):

> **Nepa:** Afrorum lingua sidus, quod cancer appelatur, vel, ut quidam volunt, scorpios.

*In a/the language of Africans, the star named "crab", or, as some would have it, "scorpion".*

He then proceeds to give a quotation from Plautus, where *nepa* is used metaphorically for an animal that could be either a kind of crab or a (water) scorpion.